# Validating SSL\TLS certificate in Unity

Tags: ssl, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with certificate validation in unity. Im using .Net class HttpWebResponse to make requests and provided callback function to ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

The certificate is signed by authority and works fine in web browser.

The validation fails with status:
**`X509ChainStatusFlags.PartialChain X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation`**

The problem, how I see it, is empty root certificate storage and empty CRLs list. I opened Mono source code and found that this data is supposed to be got from X509Store, but somehow it does not contain any of Root certificates or CRLs.

I need to implement correct validation of certificate, not just skip it by returning true in ServerCertificateValidationCallback or hardcode the certificates thumbprint, and for doing that I need to provide all the required data.

Supposing that I know the Root authority, I can add it to storage on application start. But it does not work with CRLs. The platform is Android\IOS.

The question is: How can I force unity to install Roots and CRLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can install certificate via X509Store. The installation is persist so only need to call once. According to [X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1) create a cert from Base64 or DER bytes. It can be exported by openssl: `openssl x509 -inform DER -in YOUR_ROOT_CER.cer -out YOUR_BASE64_PEM.pem`.

```
private static void InstallCertificate(byte[] cert)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
}
```

Make attentions to `StoreLocation.CurrentUser` pointed to `/data/data/<your.package.name>/.mono/` while `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` is `/usr/xxx/.mono` on android.

Comment: Attempting to do this on Unity Android, I receive the error:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "./config" is denied.
On the line "store.Add(certificate);"

What is going wrong here?

Comment: @DAVco It is another problem in old mono version, that the default path is not accessible in android. Try to use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME", <a correct path in your case>);` to change mono default path, like abstract external path `/sdcard/..` or your package `data/data/` path.