# SSL certificate validation .NET vs Mono

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, mono

I have problem with validating SSL certificate in my Unity game.

I have made simple test code which is:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;


private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}


public void Test()
{
    WebClient w = new WebClient();
    string downloadString = w.DownloadString("https://encrypted.google.com/");
}
```

I have implemented this in .NET 4.5 and in Unity (Mono) and the problem is that this certificate is validated properly on .NET, but in Mono I'm getting:

```
SslPolicyErrors: RemoteCertificateChainErrors
ChainStatus:
    PartialChain
    RevocationStatusUnknown
    OfflineRevocation
```

Why this happens? Should I set something in Mono additionally to handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mono doesn't carry any Root CA or CRL, see [Why doesn’t Mono includes root certificates](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/). And if you try to develop mobile game, there was a [cert load bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18962), which return incomplete X509Chain and was fixed in Mono 3.6.0.

According to official advices, update unity to Unity2017 will built-in mono 4.5 which solved this annoyed problem. Otherwise you may have to [install CA certs manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096376/validating-ssl-tls-certificate-in-unity/48640108#48640108).

Comment: I'm using Unity 2018.1 and still have this problem, but you at least pointed me in the right direction +1.